# How autowired RedisTemplate<String,Long>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redis

I want to use RedisTemplate on spring boot.
I can use StringRedeisTemplate successfully, but  when i cant use RedisTemplate .
here is the code.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, Long> template;

    public void execute() {
        template.opsForValue().set("hoge", 1l);
    }
}
```

But, when start apps, get errors.

```
> Exception in thread "main"
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'MyService': Injection of autowired
> dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private
> org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate
> org.hoge.service.MyService.template; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate] found for
> dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>   at
> org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
>   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
>   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
>   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
>   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
>   at
> jp.bizreach.davide.recommend.application.DavimendApplication.main(DavimendApplication.java:11)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
> com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Could not autowire field: private
> org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate
> org.hoge.service.MyService.template; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate] found for
> dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>   ... 21 more Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate] found for
> dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:530)
>   ... 23 more
```

Comment: Have you defined the bean in your xml? If yes then Could you paste you paste the relevant code.

Comment: I dont use xml.I use Autoconfiguration on spring boot

Comment: can you paste your Spring boot configurtion,where you have defined your redistemplate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The stacktrace suggest that you haven't defined the Bean which you will like to use for injecting in `RedisTemplate`.You can resolve it creating a configuration file, E.g.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericToStringSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
 @Bean
 JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
  return new JedisConnectionFactory();
 }

 @Bean
 RedisTemplate< String, Long > redisTemplate() {
  final RedisTemplate< String, Long > template =  new RedisTemplate< String, Long >();
  template.setConnectionFactory( jedisConnectionFactory() );
  template.setKeySerializer( new StringRedisSerializer() );
  template.setHashValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Long >( Long.class ) );
  template.setValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Long >( Long.class ) );
  return template;
 }
}
```

Once you have the configuration file then you need to pass it to `SpringApplication.run` E.g.

```
Object[] sources = {AppConfig.class};
ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(sources, args);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I created config file, then I can use RedisTemplate.

Comment: Thanks！ but why have to add an independent jedisConnectionFactory bean, why not could just `template.setConnectionFactory( new JedisConnectionFactory() );`

Comment: @zhuguowei If you ll not like to use/autowire ```JedisConnectionFactory``` in many places , then feel free to inline it

Comment: @sol4me, could I configure bean in applicationContext.xml?
 I did that, but it did not work. Could you help to have a look at my issue which is configure in xml? The link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449006/spring-boot-redistemplate-autoconfiguration-failed/47449147#47449147

Answer (score 4):

If you use Spring boot, add a dependency to spring-boot-starter-redis, which will bring in the redisTemplate bean. However, that bean is of type `RedisTemplate<Object, Object>`,

So create another bean for the operations that you need, as shown here [enter link description here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-redis/)

Answer (score 3):

Give something different, as now is 2018(something changes a lot which blocks me for a long time)

- First `Dependency` (Gradle)

  ```
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive')
  ```

> Remember to use the latest version, you can use gradle-use-latest-versions-plugin to check whether the dependency is latest.

1. RedisServer

   ```
   [Linux] 
   redis-server

   [spring.properties]
   spring.redis.host=localhost
   spring.redis.port=6379
   spring.cache.cache-names=orderIdPool,users
   spring.cache.redis.cache-null-values=true
   spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=600000ms
   ```
2. Redis config

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class RedisConfig {

   /**
    * create a lettuceConnectionFactory for redisTemplate {@link 
    #redisUserTemplate()}
    * @return LettuceConnectionFactory, the old version use Jedis
   */
   @Bean
   public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
       return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
   }

   /**
    * Description: aiming to create a template for Long and user(To be a user cache)
    * @return redisTemplate<Long,User>
   */
   @Bean
   @Qualifier("redisUserTemplate")
   public RedisTemplate<Long, User> redisUserTemplate() {
       RedisTemplate<Long, User> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
       redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(new LettuceConnectionFactory());
       return redisTemplate;
   }
   ```
3. use RedisTemplate

   ```
   private RedisTemplate redisTemplate
   //@Qualifier to choose the bean you actually want. 
   @Autowired
   public constructor(@Qualifier("xxxRedisTemplate")RedisTemplate redisTemplate){
     this.redisTemplate=redisTemplate;
   }
   ```
4. use redisTemplate

   ```
   private HashOperations<Long, byte[], byte[]> hashOperations = redisUserTemplate.opsForHash();
   private HashMapper<Object, byte[], byte[]> hashMapper = new ObjectHashMapper();
   @Nullable
   public void saveObject(Long key, User user) {
      Map<byte[], byte[]> mappedHash = hashMapper.toHash(user);
      hashOperations.putAll(key, mappedHash);
   }
   public Object loadObject(Long key) {
      Map<byte[], byte[]> loadedHash = hashOperations.entries(key);
      return hashMapper.fromHash(loadedHash);
   }
   ```
5. If you encounter the circular spring injection error, consider setter injection, @Lazy, @PostConstructor or implements ApplicationContextAware, InitalizingBean, for more information surf this link [how to fix this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695893/spring-security-circular-bean-dependency)

Answer (score 1):

You can do as `sol4me` said on the top, but you can handle this in a easy way:

1, auto wire `RedisTemplate`

```
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;
```

2, set value like this:

```
redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("yourkey", 12434L);
```

3, get value like this:

```
(Long) redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("yourkey");
```

No need to create a bean like `RedisTemplate< String, Long >`, if you do this like that, you may create a lot of beans in your system. So just use the easy way.

Comment: using Raw types is not a good idea. the OP wanted to use Generic types