# spring boot use redisTemplate to decr stock

Tags: redis, spring-boot

I want to compare concurrent decrement product stock in `mysql` and `redis` storage,  and I found it's not very easy to find some demo for `spring boot + redisTemplate`, from some docs I wrote below code to `decr` stock in redis

```
@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
   return new JedisConnectionFactory();
}

@Bean
RedisTemplate<String, Long> redisTemplate() {
   final RedisTemplate<String, Long> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Long>();
   template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
   template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
   template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Long>(Long.class));
   template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Long>(Long.class));
   return template;
}


private Callable<Void> updateStockInRedisTask = () -> {
    redisTemplate().execute(new RedisCallback<Long>() {
       public Long doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
           Long decr = connection.decr("1_stock".getBytes());
           return decr;
        }
    });
    return null;
};
```

and it works, but I think it's a little cumbersome， especially  compared with `jdbcTemplate`, please see below

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

private Callable<Void> updateStockInMysqlTask = () -> {
    final String sql = "update product_stock set stock = stock-1 where award_id=1 and stock>0";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
    return null;
};
```

So I'd like to know if it could be simplified？

BTW
I refered these docs:

[How autowired RedisTemplate<String,Long>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521672/how-autowired-redistemplatestring-long)

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

```
Long stock = redisTemplate.opsForValue().increment("1_stock", -1);
```